# android format sourcecode using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, formatting

I don't know how to ask this but is there a way to format android source code using a gradle task?

I am looking forward to format the code during CI/CD using a gradle task that will run after each merge request on gitlab. Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: I found this, does exactly what you need. https://medium.com/@harshitbangar/automatic-code-formatting-with-git-66c3c5c26798

Answer (score 1):

We use a gradle plugin called spotless in our spring-boot application which works our great for us.

Here's the link: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.diffplug.gradle.spotless

Comment: I know about Spotless and I have tried to use it but it got stuck on fixing wildcard imports, also can't reproduce our own code style in spotless syntax. Do you know any useful resource to do so?

Comment: I’ll ask around and research myself and if I find something I’ll comment. So do you want to apply your own custom style rules?

Comment: Ok so through some research i found a gradle plugin that will let you define custom formatting rules. It is nebula.lint and please look at the following link for more info. 

***./gradlew fixGradleLint*** can be usedd to fix any formatting issues. 

Link: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Using-Lint